# Include terms before pip install in a requirements file

Tags: python

How do I install the following using requirements.txt file (python)?

```
CT_METAL=1 pip install ctransformers --no-binary ctransformers
```

How would I phrase CT_METAL=1 in the requirements file? Or is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`--config-settings`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#install-config-settings) should do the trick.

In your specific case, the line in the requirements file must look like this:

`ctransformers --no-binary ctransformers --config-settings="CT_METAL=1"`